# How to customize theme in Semantic-UI-React (not Semantic-UI)?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to customize the theme when using Semantic-UI-React, there are detailed instructions on how to customize themes in Semantic-UI, like we can override variables to change their styles.

But I didn't find any way to customize themes with Semantic-UI-React, since there is no semantic/src/themes and semantic/src/site folders for us to make changes, what comes with Semantic-UI-React is just the default CSS file (the file we import in our index.js file "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css").

Is there any way we can customize the theme in Semantic-UI-React? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Their documentation has a page on it: [Theming - Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/theming).

Answer (score 2):

This link may also help in addition to the theming page on the docs site.

https://jsramblings.com/how-to-use-semantic-ui-with-a-custom-theme-in-your-cra-app/

It has a setup script after you run

```
npm install --save-dev semantic-ui
```

Comment: Please write the answer here. Do not post a link. Thanks.

Comment: This link may also help in addition to the theming page on the docs site.

https://jsramblings.com/how-to-use-semantic-ui-with-a-custom-theme-in-your-cra-app/

It has a setup script after you run

npm install --save-dev semantic-ui

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to customize themes and create your own
https://react.semantic-ui.com/theming/

Basically just follow instructions from the docs link, install semantic-ui-less, which are not compiled Less files for the Semantic-ui CSS, craco-less which is just a path plugin for CRA configured Webpack so your Less compiler can find files properly without ejecting your CRA, move the files to created folder, modify theme.config, start app and you are ready to customize your own theme, although I didn't find some kind of API for variables on Semantic-ui docs, so I had to browse semantic-ui-less package files for them.

One problem I encountered was that I tried changing the theme for all components in theme.config and it was throwing errors about missing fonts and variables. Don't do this, it's not gonna work, check the Semantic-ui docs about theming, there is a note about it

`Themes are per component, so although, for example, material themes are available for menu, button, and site, changing all values to "material" will produce an error for components which are not included in that theme.`

https://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html#browsing-for-themes